# Gnome “settings” not working on Fedora 34

Tags: fedora, gnome

Since I upgraded to Fedora 34, I noticed I’m not been able to open Gnome settings.

Right-clicking on wallpaper and selecting “Settings”, “Display Settings” or “Change background” have no effect either. The mouse pointer changes to a loading alike icon and returns to arrow icon after a while.

I searched web looking for this error, but i wasn’t able to find a solution. Thinking it may be some kind of conflict, I ran:

```
sudo su
dnf clean all
dnf -y distro-sync
dnf remove --duplicates
dnf update
```

This removed duplicated packages and updated them, but had no effect on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve it this way: I tryed to run `gnome-control-center` and got the following error message.

> gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libwebpdemux.so.2: file too short

Since this error usually indicates a broken .so file, I reinstalled the thing it belongs to, in this case that's **libwebp**.

```
sudo dnf reinstall libwebp
```

That resolved the problem.